# Can ChromeBooks run android apps?

Tags: android, chromebook

I am wondering if Chromebooks have any ability to run some sort of android app, as I am developing an android app but I do not have anywhere to test it (my only phone is an iPhone X, which of course cannot run Android apps.)
Does anybody know if Chromebooks are capable of running Android apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All Chromebooks since 2017 can run Android Apps plus a few from 2016 but I would only get one if you want to use it as a laptop since the Android app experience is a bit different than on a phone.  I suggest you ask a friend to test your app on their phone.

Answer (score 1):

My Google Pixelbook (2017) can run almost any android app. It runs them almost seamlessly. The newer Chrome OS versions run android natively, so it is almost the same as running android apps on a android tablet. They cannot run apps built exclusively for phones.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible (see http://fortune.com/2018/11/27/review-google-pixel-slate-tablet/ for a not-ancient state of play) - but, I suspect not perfect and s very bad test platform.